# Unable to access a property of an object using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

## **Sample data:**

```json
{
  "_id": "ObjectId_for_Site1",
  "name": "Site 1",
  "address": "123 Reeganangam",
  "manager": {
    "_id": "ObjectId_for_Manager1",
    "name": "Karthik",
    "type": "Manager"
  }
}
```

## **Controller**

```
const getAllSites = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const sites = await Site.find();
    console.log(sites);
    res.status(200).json(sites);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
};
```

## **Schema:**

```
const managerSchema = new Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  type: String,
});

const siteSchema = new Schema({
  _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name: String,
  address: String,
  manager: managerSchema,
});

const Site = mongoose.model('Site', siteSchema, 'Site_Collection');
```

## **Where controller is referenced:**

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const sites = await siteController.getAllSites();

    if (sites && Array.isArray(sites)) {
      const siteNames = sites.map((site) => site.name);
      res.render('main', {
        profile_picture_url: 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fhSUOv08fdHzl7r98Hy8_MAGVt3N7loL/view?usp=sharing',
        username: 'Sundar',
        sites: siteNames,
      });
    } else {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch sites data' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});
```

Note: I encountered an issue while attempting to access a property of an object using Mongoose. While I could successfully retrieve a response via the URL http://localhost:3000/api/site, I encountered an error when trying to access http://localhost:3000/main. The error message received is as follows:

`{"error":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')"}`

Comment: why you're sending two responses, one from the `getAllSites` controller and the other from the `router.get()` ? also, I wondering if this line is working `const siteNames = sites.map((site) => site.name);` can you print the `siteNames` variable ?

Comment: The culprit is `res.status(200).json(sites);` in Controller. when I change to something like this `return sites` It just works. In `router.get()` , I'm trying to databind using pug which requires routing and datafetching. that is what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up removing **siteNames** and the second response. good catch! It's always good to have another pair of eyes. much appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a response from the `getAllSites` controller, once you send a response the request-response cycle gets closed that's why the `response.render()` that is inside the router can't be processed

I've reorganised your code a little, please try out it and inform me if it worked out or not :

```
const getAllSites = async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const sites = await Site.find();
      if (sites && Array.isArray(sites)) {
        const siteNames = sites.map((site) => site.name);
        res.status(200).render('main', {
          profile_picture_url: '[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fhSUOv08fdHzl7r98Hy8_MAGVt3N7loL/view?usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fhSUOv08fdHzl7r98Hy8_MAGVt3N7loL/view?usp=sharing)',
          username: 'Sundar',
          sites: siteNames,
        });
      } 
      else {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch sites data' });
      }  
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
  };

router.get('/', siteController.getAllSites);
```

Comment: It didn't work. I tried the above the change. but, fortunately. I found the culprit.
`const getAllSites =  async (req, res) => {
    try{
        const sites = await Site.find({});
        return sites; // Returning only the sites not res.status(200)
    }catch (error){
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
};
`
but, Thanks for A2A. Please validate if this correct, is there any implications/pifalls with this approach, that may resurface in future? thanks again :)

Comment: Sorry but I can't understand if your code worked and  you managed to get the wanted result or not, you're saying that my code didn't work but also you're saying you know what is causing the error

Comment: sorry, let rephrase, I mean to say it didn't make any difference. whether `res.status(200).render() or res.render()`. The issue caused by this line in controller : `res.status(200).json(sites);` since response is returning status here. Hence the error :
{"error":"Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')"}

Comment: so I just did `return await Site.find();` it works again. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that you managed to fix the code